# how to create a web part to track page creation time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am new to SharePoint Server 2007 Web Part, and I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I program using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

I want to create a simple web part which could display page creation time and modified time (display such time information at the bottom of a web page).

Any reference code samples or tutorials -- anything helpful for a newbie of SharePoint 2007 Web Part or this specific time tracking issue is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example, implemented as a custom footer

http://itfootprint.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/sharepoint-footer-custom-control-last-modified-date/

Comment: How to make it beside the title of the page (i.e. put the last modified time between title and content)?

Comment: You could place the code from the link into the correct place in the master page or page template